# Android sort array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i have a string array consisting of a name and a score. I want to sort that array by score. Problem is, considering it's a string array, the scores are strings which results in 13,16,2,5,6 and not 2,5,6,13,16. I am using this code:

```
int spaceIndex;
String[][] scoreboard;
String[] playername;
String[] score;
int sbsize;

array1.add("Thomas" + ":" + 5);
array1.add("Blueb" + ":" + 6);
array1.add("James" + ":" + 16);
array1.add("Hleb" + ":" + 13);
array1.add("Sabbat" + ":" + 2);
sbsize = array1.size();
scoreboard = new String[sbsize][2];
playername = new String[sbsize];
score = new String[sbsize];
pos2 = new int[sbsize];

for (int i=0; i<array1.size(); i++)
{
    spaceIndex =  array1.get(i).indexOf(':'); 
    scoreboard[i][0] = array1.get(i).substring(0, spaceIndex);
    scoreboard[i][1] = array1.get(i).substring(spaceIndex+1, array1.get(i).length());
}

Arrays.sort(scoreboard, new Comparator<String[]>() {
 @Override
 public int compare(String[] entry1, String[] entry2) {
    String time1 = entry1[1];
    String time2 = entry2[1];
    return time1.compareTo(time2);
    }
 });
```

What is the solution?

Comment: If that's score, why not store it in integer? OK, even not store in integer, you can cast it to integer and compare.

Comment: needful url to sort arry http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-an-array-in-java/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cast them to int. As I recall, something like...

```
Arrays.sort(scoreboard, new Comparator<String[]>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(String[] entry1, String[] entry2) {
        Integer time1 = Integer.valueOf(entry1[1]);
        Integer time2 = Integer.valueOf(entry2[1]);
        return time1.compareTo(time2);
        }
     });
```

Also you can make simple value object class for easier manipulations. Like...

```
class Player
{
  public String name;
  public int score;
}
```

And after that you can make

```
 Player[] scoreboard = ...
 Arrays.sort(scoreboard, new Comparator<Player>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(Player player1, Player player2) {
              if(player1.score > player2.score) return 1;
              else if(player1.score < player2.score) return -1;
              else return 0;            
             }
 });
```

Edit: 
I recommend you to understand the basic OOP principles, this will help you a lot in the beginning.

Edit 2: **Java 8 (with functional interface and a lambda):**

```
Arrays.sort(scoreboard, (player1, player2) -> {
  Integer time1 = Integer.valueOf(player1[1]);
  Integer time2 = Integer.valueOf(player2[1]);
  return time1.compareTo(time2);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i wanted exactly this!

Answer (score 7):

This is the easy way of Sorting String Array:
Arrays.sort(mystringarray);

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(yourArray, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(object1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(object2));
        }
    });
```

Comparator will compare your strings as integers.

Comment: The answer is convert to numbers to sort as numbers - If not you are sorting in lexical order if you keep them as strings +1

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("sathish");
    names.add("Ravi");
    names.add("Praksh");
    names.add("pavithara");
    names.add("Duraga");
    names.add("uma");
    names.add("Upendar");
    System.out.println("Before sorting");
    System.out.println("Names : "+names);
    Collections.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            return lhs.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs);//Ascending order.
            //return (lhs.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs)*(-1));//Descending order.

        }
    });
    System.out.println("After sorting");
    System.out.println("Names : "+names);
```

output:
Before sorting

Names : [sathish, Ravi, Praksh, pavithara, Duraga, uma, Upendar]

After sorting

Names : [Duraga, pavithara, Praksh, Ravi, sathish, uma, Upendar]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` instead of `Array`.

Please check [this link](http://www.java-examples.com/sort-elements-java-arraylist-example)

Answer (score 0):

If possible use better data structure for your problem, use HashMap, with name to score mapping and , sort the hashmap with values.
If you want to go with arraylist as described by you, before sorting, convert them into integer and sort, then back to string.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off storing the names + results in objects, then storing those in an ArrayList. You can then sort very easily using a custom comparator, see the link for a simple example: http://www.javabeat.net/tips/20-sorting-custom-types-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Score should be a class like

```
public class HighScore Comparable<HighScore>
{
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Score( String name, int score )
    {
         this.name = name; 
         this.score = score;
    }//cons

    //getters
    public String getName() { 
         return name;
    }//met

    public int getScore() { 
         return score;
    }//met

    @Override
    public int compareTo( HighScrore b )
    {
          int diffScore = score - b.score;
          if( diffScore != 0)
              return diffScore;
          else
              return name.compareTo( b.name );
    }//met

    public boolean equals( Object o )
    {
         if( !(o instanceof HighScore))   
             return false;
         HighScore b = (HighScore) o;
         return score == b.score && name.equals( b.name );
    }//met
}//class
```

Then you can build score objects,

```
String[] stringParts[];
List<HighScore> listHighScore = new ArrayList<HighScore>();
for (int i=0; i<array1.size(); i++)
{
    stringParts =  array1.get(i).split(':'); 
    listHighScore.add( new HighScore( stringParts[ 0 ], Integer.parseInt( stringParts[ 1 ])) );

}//for
```

put them in a List and sort them through

```
Collections.sort( list );
```

Regards, 
  Stéphane