# How to sort a multi column list view(by second column) getting values from a custom base adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I have an arrayList "listItems" with multiple objects, each having an "Item Name" and "Item Price".

I create a custom base adapter "adapterItems" and in my activity I set the adapter to the list

```
AdapterItems adapterItems = new AdapterItems(MyActivity.this, listItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapterItems);
```

Everything works fine and all the items are displated in my activity as a list view in the order the objects were added to the arrayList.

Now I want to sort this list by ascending order of item price.

I am ok to sort the listItems first before giving it to the adapter OR sort the listview adapter later on. How can I do either/both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to sort your listview.

[See this Example That compare name and sort it in Alphabetical order](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html)

**in your case::**

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

    public String name;
    public int price;

    public int compareTo(Item another) {
        return (this.price-another.price);
    }
}
```

**And**

> **Collections.sort(yourlist);**

Answer (score 0):

Check below link...

[Android Sort Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224978/android-sort-array)

Above link sort score same as require you sort price...

OR

Create Custom Comparable like..

```
Comparator<Item > comperator = new Comparator<Item >() 
{
    @Override               
    public int compare(Item  object1, Item  object2) {                  
        float First = Float.parseFloat(object1.price);                      
        float Second = Float.parseFloat(object2.price);                     
        return (First < Second ? -1 : (First == Second ? 0 : 1));           
    }
};

Collections.sort(Itemdata, comperator);
```

when item is your class and Itemdata is arraylist of class item.