# Android: How to sort FTPFile[] filelist by date?

Tags: android, list, ftp

I like to sort a `FTPFile` list by `date` and don't know how I can do this.

I have the following code:

```
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();

for (FTPFile file : files) {
    imageUrls.add("http://XXXXXXX/xx/xx/" + file.getName());
    imageNames.add(file.getName());
}
```

But when I display this on a device it's ordered by `filename`.
So how can I order `files` by `date`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get date:

```
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("File last modified @ : "+ lastModDate.toString());
```

for sorting you will need a custom comparator, that you can read up on here [Android sort array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224978/android-sort-array)

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<file>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
          if (file1.lastModified() > file2.lastModified()) { return 1; }
          else if (file1.lastModified() < file2.lastModified()) { return -1; }
          else { return 0; }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can fetch the [last modified](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) date for a file with

```
File file = new File(filePath);
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("File last modified @ : "+ lastModDate.toString());
```

Then,

```
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
    public int compare(File f1, File f2)
    {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    } });
```