# android Arrange data in descending order

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have following data in string(comma format) (Name,Mark)

A,20,B,10,C,30

I want to convert into Descending order like :

C,30,A,29,B,10

Please help me how can i implement in android ?

Here is code what i have prepared....

public class custom_sort {

```
    public String name;
    public int mark;

    public custom_sort(String a, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        name = a;
        mark = b;
    }

    void setname(String s)
    {
        name=s;
    }

    void setmark(int s)
    {
        mark = s;
    }

    String getname()
    {
        return(name);
    }

    int getmark()
    {
        return(mark);
    }


}
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Have tried any thing. Use `Map`, Name as key and Mark as value. Next sort this map. You need string split operations also.

Comment: What is holding the data? What have you tried?

Comment: Data is in string array, Its very difficult to do... someone suggest me to use collection framework... but stuckup in list so don't know how to resolve

Comment: Please help me, i have revised que with code which i have tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. I see that you have already made a class: custom_sort. We can use this to sort it, if we just make it comparable. We do this by implementing the Comparable interface.

```
public class custom_sort implements Comparable{
```

Then all you need to do is implement the one required method:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(custom_sort cs) {
       /*
       This method should return 0 if the two objects are equal,
       1 if this is biggest 
       and -1 if cs is biggest */
    }
```

Then you can put all the custom_sorts in an List and just do Arrays.sort(yourArray).

You could also check out this post [Android sort array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224978/android-sort-array)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import android.support.v4.util.Pair;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

String[] values = {"A", "20", "B", "10", "C", "30"};
List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
    pairs.add(new Pair<>(values[i], Integer.parseInt(values[i + 1])));
}
Collections.sort(pairs, new Comparator<Pair>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pair lhs, Pair rhs) {
        return ((Integer) rhs.second).compareTo((Integer) lhs.second);
    }
});
```

The List pairs is now sorted like you wish. Check out the Pair class i used http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html

And if you want to convert it back following code will help you:

```
String[] newValues = new String[values.length];
int i = 0;
for (Pair pair : pairs) {
    newValues[i] = (String) pair.first;
    newValues[i + 1] = Integer.toString((Integer) pair.second);
    i += 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I am getting error on import android.support.v4.util.Pair;

Comment: use import android.util.Pair; instead

Answer (score 1):

Use `ArrayList` rather than array of string.

This might not be the best solution but it works.

**Initialize the `ArrayList`**

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Fill data inside the `ArrayList`**

```
names.add("A");
scores.add(20);
....
```

**Now sort them**

```
private void sortScoreAndName() {
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (scores.get(i) > scores.get(j))
                swap(i, j);
        }
    }
}

private void swap(int i, int j) {
    int tempSco = scores.get(i);
    String tempName = names.get(i);
    scores.remove(i);
    names.remove(i);
    scores.add(i, scores.get(j));
    names.add(i, names.get(j));
    scores.remove(j);
    names.remove(j);
    scores.add(j, tempSco);
    names.add(j, tempName);
}
```

Now your ArrayList is in descending order. You can get the corresponding data using.

```
names.get(poition);
scores.get(position);
```